# Web API: Make action parameter mandatory

Tags: asp.net-web-api, parameters, null

I have an action that looks thus:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostInstantiation(Guid id, [FromBody]Instantiation instantiation)
```

If the user does a POST to the correct URL, but with no (/empty) body, then model validation doesn't fail, and the instantiation argument is null.  I expected it to fail.

What is the correct way of handling this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are noticing is an expected behavior. If you indeed would like to check if the user has sent an empty body, then you could probably check for the `Content-Length` header of the incoming request.

`if(Request.Content.Headers.ContentLength == 0)`

Comment: Or, I could just do: if (instantiation == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(); I was hoping there would be an attribute I could apply, in addition to [FromBody], to indicate that it was a required parameter.  Sadly the [Required] attribute doesn't do the case here.

Comment: The issue with checking like `if(instantation==null)` is that, let's say you are using web api's Json and Xml formatters at your client. These formatters will serialize `null` in case of Json formatter and corresponding Xml formatter will have its own representation, that is the body will have a value. So you would need to figure out if indeed there is a body or not.